# background-size: cover on android/iOS

Tags: android, html, ios, css

so I have this html markup:

```
<div class="nav"></div>
<div class="content></div>

.nav{
   background: url(...) no-repeat center center fixed; 
   -webkit-background-size: cover;
   -moz-background-size: cover;
   -o-background-size: cover;
   background-size: cover;
   z-index: 10;
   position: fixed;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   width: 100%;
   height: 80px;
}
```

The .nav element is fixed positioned with background-image and background-size: cover set. It also has a higher z-index than .content element, so that the .content would hide behind the .nav when scrolling down the page.
This setup works well in browsers but fails on android/iOS (the background image on .nav element becomes transparent and does not hide the .content).
Any ideas?

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/amp1Lyjq/1/

This part is a fix for iOS momentum scrolling:

overflow-y: scroll;
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;

Comment: Please, provide jsfiddle

Comment: Here you go, any help appreciated